# Как обновить структуру БД MS SQL через Managment Studio

Tags: sql

Добрый день!

Есть Managment Studio в которой есть подключение к двум (или более) базам.

Есть тестовая БД на которой все тестируется и рабочая.
В тестовой время от времени добавляются поля, связи, хранимые процедуры.

Как обновить структуру рабочей базы - т.е. сделать такую же как и в тестовой без изменения самих данных в рабочей базе.
Спасибо.

Comment: подозреваю ответом будет "руками" или советы сторонних утилит.

Comment: Да как же так???...

Comment: можно генерировать и сохранять скрипты изменения структуры на тестовой базе, потом пачкой выполнить на рабочей.

Comment: А подробней можно как-то????